# Docker for Mac `docker images` command returns "fatal error: fault"

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

After pulling an image from docker hub `docker images list` won't list the image and i receive a fatal error: fault on `docker images` command

```
$ docker images list
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
$
$ docker images
unexpected fault address 0xb01dfacedebac1e
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0x14f3af]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x5bda98, 0x5)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90 fp=0xc82013cdb0 sp=0xc82013cd98
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:27 +0x2ba fp=0xc82013ce00 sp=0xc82013cdb0
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).write0(0xc8201a0000, 0xc820186160, 0xa, 0x14a)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:215 +0x5f fp=0xc82013ce70 sp=0xc82013ce00
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).writeLines(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:282 +0x4da fp=0xc82013cfb8 sp=0xc82013ce70
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).format(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:370 +0x317 fp=0xc82013d070 sp=0xc82013cfb8
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).format(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:363 +0x2a9 fp=0xc82013d128 sp=0xc82013d070
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).format(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:363 +0x2a9 fp=0xc82013d1e0 sp=0xc82013d128
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).format(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:363 +0x2a9 fp=0xc82013d298 sp=0xc82013d1e0
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).format(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:363 +0x2a9 fp=0xc82013d350 sp=0xc82013d298
text/tabwriter.(*Writer).Flush(0xc8201a0000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go:466 +0x1f0 fp=0xc82013d3e8 sp=0xc82013d350
github.com/docker/docker/api/client.(*DockerCli).CmdImages(0xc8200a8300, 0xc82000a1b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/docker20151015-58839-tt61q3/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/client/images.go:127 +0x1be7 fp=0xc82013db08 sp=0xc82013d3e8
runtime.call64(0xc8200155e0, 0x5b67c8, 0xc820141f50, 0x2000000030)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:438 +0x3e fp=0xc82013db50 sp=0xc82013db08
reflect.callMethod(0xc820141f20, 0xc82013dc28)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:628 +0x1fc fp=0xc82013dc10 sp=0xc82013db50
reflect.methodValueCall(0xc82000a1b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc820141f20, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820141f20, 0xc820160180, 0x66444, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/reflect/asm_amd64.s:29 +0x36 fp=0xc82013dc28 sp=0xc82013dc10
github.com/docker/docker/cli.(*Cli).Run(0xc820141b60, 0xc82000a1b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /private/tmp/docker20151015-58839-tt61q3/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/cli/cli.go:89 +0x383 fp=0xc82013dd10 sp=0xc82013dc28
main.main()
    /private/tmp/docker20151015-58839-tt61q3/docker/docker.go:69 +0x400 fp=0xc82013df00 sp=0xc82013dd10
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:111 +0x2b0 fp=0xc82013df50 sp=0xc82013df00
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc82013df58 sp=0xc82013df50

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 7 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0xe65ea8, 0x72, 0xc820010160)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc82015cf40, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc82015cf40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc82015cee0, 0xc820155000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0xe60050, 0xc820010160)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/fd_unix.go:232 +0x23a
net.(*conn).Read(0xc8200300e8, 0xc820155000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/net.go:172 +0xe4
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0xe65f68, 0xc8200300e8, 0xc820096108, 0xc820155000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:1370 +0x67
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc82014d3a0, 0xc820155000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:126 +0xd0
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc820018f60)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1e9
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0xc820018f60, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xcc
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc8200960b0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:876 +0xf7
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:685 +0xc78

goroutine 8 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc8200960b0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:1009 +0x40c
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec/src/net/http/transport.go:686 +0xc9d
```

However I'm still able to run the recently pulled image just fine with `docker run`.

This is Docker for Mac version: 18.03.1-ce-mac-65 (24312).  It's a new install on a macbook pro.

I tried googling this but couldn't find anything.  Any one have an idea as to what's going on?

Comment: Did you use brew or the installer from the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is it conflicted with an old docker installed via brew.  That's why there's a lot of mention of "Cellar" in the output.  Once i uninstalled the brew version of docker the commands worked and the images listed as expected.

Comment: sorry I did not scroll down enough. glad you found your answer!